# Where's the HTML in PHP template files?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

So I am new to web development, and want to begin developing themes for Wordpress.

I am confident in my HTML and CSS skills but I am somewhat stuck on understanding how PHP works specifically for Wordpress.

To get straight to the point, when I download a basic theme from wordpress.org and look inside all of the template files, I don't see any HTML code.

I am familiar with the get function in php and so on, but watching videos/tutorials on theme development has confused me so much.

For example, most of all the tutorials I have watched shows someone copy and pasting HTML code from their static web templates directly into the PHP files. (index.php and so on). It works and I am told that is a correct method of doing it, but I just don't understand why I don't can't see HTML code in wordpress themes I download.

Is there a way of not showing the HTML?

Thanks you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

The html code is inside the PHP file. there are various way to write HTML inside a PHP file. For example

```
<?php
echo "<html><h1>header</h1></html>";
?>
```

Save the above code as PHP and run it on the server You will get html output from PHP file.

You can also run it in the following way

```
<?php
//your first php code here//
?>

<html>
 my html here
</htm>

<?php
//your second php code here//
?>
```

It is the right way to write html code inside a php file. you can't run php code on a html file so the html code should be written on the PHP file.

========question answer==========

this is the theme you have mentioned : https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen

check the index.php file
https://github.com/WordPress/twentyseventeen/blob/master/index.php

you will see

```
    get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
    <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
        <header class="page-header">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
</header>
```

this type of coding there.

```
<h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
```

Look carefully the line. `<h1 class="page-title">` it is a html tag ( it is html code )

You can download the theme on your pc and open the index.php file and others file. you will see html code but it is mixed with PHP.

Comment: I understand that you can write HTML in PHP, which is what I will do. But I want to understand why in the TwentySeventeen theme from Wordpress, there is no HTML present in any of the .php files?

Comment: i have edited the answer . Hope you have found the html code. html code is mixed with PHP, that's why you cant detect them. for example

<h1 class="page-title"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>

here <h1 class="page-title"> is html code but <?php single_post_title(); ?> is php code again </h1> is html

Comment: For some reason, the code you mentioned wasn't showing on my editor. Weird. But now I see. Thank you very much. Also another question. Do you personally build a theme from scratch (with a static html template which you then convert into php) or do you use an existing theme to make a child theme and then develop from there?

Comment: i'm not wordpress theme developer. i have developed many PHP CMS, actually you have to code both html and php together if you want to build someting. PHP do the logical thing and html is rquired to display the result. it will be more difficult if you try to write html first then PHP. If you are a new developer i recommend you to use an existing theme. making something from scratch is difficult so i do not recommend it to the new developer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install WAMP on your localhost.

There are PHP files for Wordpress that alter how it functions but I would not recommend you edit these unless you know what you are doing.

If you install Wordpress on WAMP you will have access to all this and can also set up specific projects on WAMP to develop and test your themes.

There is a good walk through here on setting it up https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-set-up-wordpress-locally-for-pcwindows-with-wamp/?utm_expid=3606929-106.UePdqd0XSL687behGg-9FA.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you'll do with Wordpress templates is use HTML to hold the info you get from PHP, such as the page/post title, content, tags, categories, etc. You could do something like

`<h1 class="title-class"><?php get_the_title();?></h1>`

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to hide html and there is no point to do that either.
But if you look carefully in wp-content -> themes folder you will see all themes directories.

there you can find html "code". In some case you won't find any .html files, may be.

Reason for it because wordpress theme's all pages contains atleast one dynamic part like header. so to make html page dynamic you need to set .php extension for files instead of .html or .htm.

You will find less html and more php sometimes because mostly wordpress themes coded with reusable snippets and functions who generates some code blocks.

But there is html code blended with php code inside .php files:

for example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title><?php get_the_title(); ?></title>
    <?php get_custom_css_files(); ?>
  </head>
  <body class="container">
    <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
    <?php foreach($posts as $post) {
      <div class="title"><?php echo post['title']; ?></div>
      <div class="desc"><?php echo post['text']; ?></div>
    <?php } ?>   
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that there will be no HTML files as Wordpress is dynamic and requires the .php files. What I am trying to understand is when I download the TwentySeventeen theme and look through the .php templates, I see no HTML code whatsoever. But when I watch tutorials I see them inputting HTML code along with the PHP. But the question I am trying to get at is why can I not see any HTML in the TwentySeventeen files?